# Unity3D Splash screen for multiple resolutions in android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am playing with Unity3D and has tried to making a small and simple game. Now wanted to include a splash screen. Since the free version of Unity3D doesn't allow directly choosing the image for splash screen in `Player Settings`, I have followed this documentation: [HOWTO-Splash screen in Unity3D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-SplashScreen.html)

What I have done is, created a new Scene. Then drag and dropped my PNG image of size 1024x512 px to the Assets. Then clicked on this image and then in the Import Settings pane, I had chosen the Texture Type to `Texture` and hits Apply button.

Then I had created a new Cube object by going to *Game Object --> Create Other --> Cube*. Then for this cube, I have the values 0 for the 3 coordinates, and (16,9) for the x,y scaling.

Then dragged and dropped this splash screen image from the Assets window to this Cube. But the rendering gives the image inverted vertically! Also, the image was in White background with some text in it. But in the rendered window(ie. Game), it is in faded color!

Where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are two issues:

1. I suspect the shader that your cube uses relies on lighting which is why you're getting a faded colour. If that's the case, change the shader on the material to an unlit shader.
2. The image inverted vertically is a bit odd but I suspect you could scale the cube negatively on whatever axis is incorrect.

I suspect the splash screen may be easier to create with Unity's sprite system.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the shader like you said and it is working now. And I changed the scaling to (-16,-9) for (x,y) for the Cube and it is now showing the image perfectly. :)